# django form constructor not returning fields?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

for some reason i'm unable to populate a form's fields as i have in the past.  here are the relevant bits:

views.py

```
def selectEvent(request, user=None):
    if not user:
        userID = request.user.id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        qform = eventForm(request.POST, user=userID)
        if qform.is_valid():
            qryData = qform.cleaned_data
            event = qryData['event']
            qurl = '/showGG/getWedGuest/%s' % (event)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(qurl)
    else:
        qform = eventForm(user=userID)

    return render(request, 'showGG/getEvent.html', {'form': qform})
```

forms.py

```
class eventForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user=kwargs.pop('user')
        super(eventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        elist = [(e,e.name) for e in Event.objects.filter(organizer_id__exact=user)]
        print 'eventForm: elist=',elist
        event = forms.ChoiceField(choices=elist)
```

i need the complicated `eventForm.__init__()` cuz i'm passing it a variable, but the print line
shows that it is producing the list i expect:

```
eventForm: elist= [(<Event: cd2 - 2013-08-01 00:17:39+00:00>, u'cd2')]
```

but when i get the returned `qform` back in `views.selectEvent`, both its `fields` and `base_fields` variables are empty dictionaries?  why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't defined any fields on the form. You can't just set them in `__init__` and hope that will work: there's complicated metaclass stuff going on, and the definitions have to be at the class level. What you can do in `__init__` is override the choices of the existing field:

```
class eventForm(forms.Form):
    event = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user=kwargs.pop('user')
        super(eventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        elist = [(e.id,e.name) for e in Event.objects.filter(organizer_id__exact=user)]
        self.fields['event'].choices = elist
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, i could tell i was playing with meta- bits(:  but your `self.fields['event'].choices = elist` throws a KeyError regarding `event`, whether or not i put `event = forms.ChoiceField()` line before this?

Comment: to be clear, if i put  your `event = forms.ChoiceField()` line before the `def __init__`, or after it, i get the same empty fields list behavior.

Comment: Daniel,  your solution works!  the "empty fields" behavior i described turned out to be the result of a different different bug.  thanks!